# Will RestKit's dynamic mapping solve this complex JSON mapping?

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am using RestKit in my app, which needs to use an existing synchronization service that structures the incoming data this way:

```
{
  "timestamp": 000000000001,
  "status" : 0,
  "syncData":[
    {
      "errors":[],
      "rows":[ {"name":"AAA", ...},
               {"name":"BBB", ...}, 
               ...],
      "rtype":"FOO" },
    {
      "errors":[],
      "rows":[ {"id":1, "description":"ZZZ", ....},
               {"id":2, "description":"YYY", ....}, 
               ...],
      "rtype":"BAR"
    }, ...
```

I'm new to RestKit and trying to figure out the best way to solve this problem, and the complementary problem of sending this same structure of data back to the server. I'm using Core Data with RestKit.

I've mapped a SyncResponse entity to hold the top level data, and what I want to get out of this is a collection of FOO objects, "AAA", "BBB", etc., and a collection of BAR objects, "ZZZ", "YYY", etc., and a few dozen other collections of objects whose Class is indicated by the "rtype" field.

I've read the doc section on dynamic mapping and some example code and postings here, but I don't see how dynamic mapping works in this case as it is not of the `{"a":{is A}, "b":{is B}}` format. Is this possible using dynamic mapping, and if so, what concepts am I missing here?

Assuming it is possible, how do I, starting with collections of FOOs and BARs send data back, of course replacing the SyncResponse with something like a SyncUpdateRequest wrapper?

Comment: Tricky, because the mapping would want the `syncData` to contain all the same items.

Comment: Can the `syncData` have many different types, and can the order of the types change?

Comment: The order will not likely change, not without notice, but it will contain many different types. There are ~20 that I have to deal with now. Can I intercept the attempt to match each one and provide a distinct mapping for each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to do this using a set of mappings alone.

Your best option may be to create your mappings for each item and one for the overall structure. The overall mapping just extracts the array as an `NSArray` of dictionaries. Once you have the array you can iterate over it yourself, check the type and then apply an `RKMapperOperation` to perform the mappings.

---

For sending your update request, I'd look at it as a quite separate thing. I'd build an array of dictionaries where the dictionaries have 'plain' key / value pairs for some information and 'complex' key / value pairs for the `rows`. Your request mapping is then in terms of this array of dictionaries (which cover the custom parts) and the rows (which should be the inverse of your response mapping for the class). Then RestKit should be able to handle it in the standard way (compared to the complexity of your response mapping above).

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense and would likely be the quickest way to get this working, but how do I indicate that I want an array of dictionaries returned?

Comment: RestKit examines the data type or a mapping destination to decide what to do. So, create an `NSMutableArray` property on the destination class or set the mapping class to `NSMutableArray` depending on exactly how you're going to manage the process.

Comment: OK, thanks Wain, that gets me the data as dictionaries and arrays. But I'm not finding much information on how to set up RKMapperOperation for this kind of use. I take it that I need to create the FOO and BAR mapping and pass the value of each "rows" object? I'm off to give it a try!

Comment: I coded a solution using RKMapperOperation. The mapper is returning with objects in mapper.mappingResult, but they seem to be the source dictionaries. I want them mapped to Core Data NSManagedObject objects. Is it not waiting for the queue to finish the mapping? The RKMapperOperation header isn't specific about how to get a handle on the queue and I can't find a real example of it being used. What am I missing?

Comment: You might want to start a new question so you can show the code.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234480/feeding-parsed-data-to-rkmapperoperation-throws-nsunknownkeyexception

Comment: Thanks for answering the other question, but now back to part two of this question. I need to now create the identical structure to send back to the server if I update these objects. Is there a corresponding way to trap the request creation?

Comment: Added some more details.