# RestKit complex and simple JSON RKObjectMapping almost working, but

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have been researching this issue.  Here are a few discoveries that will help map this JSON response in RestKit

The JSON response object contains three top level objects :
locations is an array 
cityKey object
stateKey object

`Since Restkit is written in Objective-C, I looked at it as if I were going to directing` map these objects and parse-out data

I wrote the following code to map the NSDictionary portion of the Location Class\Object:

```
    RKObjectMapping* locationMapping = [RKObjectMapping       mappingForClass:[Location class]];
     [locationMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                             @"distance": @"distance",
                             @"major": @"major",
                             @"minor": @"minor" }];
```

I wrote the following code for the overall class\object , Locations: //This should also be an NSDictionary

```
    RKObjectMapping *locationsMapping = RKObjectMapping       mappingforclass: [Locations class]];

This appears to be a mapping array should be a dictionary.

    [locationsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"locations", @"cityKey",@"stateKey"]];
```

I see the error in the use of Array for the overall object Locations. This runs and returns a partially successful result from the following:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *locationDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:locationMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:@"/location" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager]    addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager]    addResponseDescriptor:locationDescriptor];



[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:nil path:(_enterLocation) parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
     NSLog(@"It Worked: %@", [mappingResult array]);


} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"It Failed: %@", error);

  }];

This returns the successful responseJSONdata, but mappingResult dictionary returns:

2014-05-07 17:28:39.770 MyApp[163:60b] It Worked: {
    locations =  (
    );

}

The actual JSONOBJECTWITHDATA returned as response.body is:

response.body={
  "locations": [
    {
      "distance": 0.5, 
      "major": 2, 
      "minor": 4, 
      
    }, 
    {
      "distance": 1.0, 
      "major": 2, 
      "minor": 11, 
      
    }
  ], 
  "cityKey": "12", 
  "stateKey": "41"
}
```

From reading,

[Will RestKit's dynamic mapping solve this complex JSON mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189587/will-restkits-dynamic-mapping-solve-this-complex-json-mapping/19191820)

and

[Feeding parsed data to RKMapperOperation throws NSUnknownKeyException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234480/feeding-parsed-data-to-rkmapperoperation-throws-nsunknownkeyexception)

I know that I need to change my approach to RestKit mapping.  For the complex case

Even in the simple case, I am only returning a pointer to the object.

```
 RKObjectMapping *statusResponseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[StatusResponse class]];

    [statusResponseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"status":@"status"}]; 

RKResponseDescriptor *statusResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:statusResponseMapping method:RKRequestMethodPOST pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"response" statusCodes:statusCodes];
```

I receive the correct response from the server...but only get a pointer

```
 response.body={
      "response": {
        "status": "ok"
      }
    }
    2014-05-07 17:11:47.362 MyApp[145:60b] It Worked: {
        response = "<StatusResponse: 0x16ee2e10>";

    }
```

I am missing key step or mapping definition.  I am almost to the desired result.

What do I need to do to get the desired results in both the simple and complex cases?

UPDATED MY QUESTION WITH THE NEW INFORMATION BELOW

Updated today may 8 2014, I changed locationsMapping code to...

```
RKObjectMapping *locationsMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Locations class]];
    [locationsMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"locations" toKeyPath:@"locations" withMapping:locationMapping]];
```

Which moved it a step closer to correctly mapping.  The result was...

```
2014-05-08 13:28:17.795 MyApp[165:60b] It Worked: {
    locations =     (
        "<Locations: 0x14e69a10>",
        "<Locations: 0x14e695c0>"
    );
```

Which is almost correct. I appear to be missing mapping for the cityKey and StateKey. I have not defined the Description method.  Here is the raw JSON data returned...

```
response.body={
  "locations": [
    {
      "distance": 0.6, 
      "major": 2, 
      "minor": 4 

    }, 
    {
      "distance": 1.0, 
      "major": 2, 
      "minor": 11 

    }
  ], 
  "cityKey": "11", 
  "stateKey": "21"
}
```

Mapping does not return the cityKey and stateKey...something is still missing in the mapping definition?

UPDATED MAY 9 2014 AFTER CHANGING locationMapping as suggested

```
RKObjectMapping *locationsMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Locations class]];

    [locationsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[
 @"cityKey",@"stateKey"]];

    [locationsMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"locations" toKeyPath:@"locations" withMapping:locationMapping]];


response.body={
  "locations": [
    {
      "distance": 0.6, 
      "major": 2, 
      "minor": 4
    }, 
    {
      "distance": 1.0, 
      "major": 2, 
      "minor": 11
    }
  ], 
  "cityKey": "10", 
  "stateKey": "15"
}
2014-05-09 13:18:17.669 MyApp[211:60b] It Worked: {
    locations  =     (
        "<Locations: 0x1780341e0>",
        "<Locations: 0x170027c40>"
    );
}
```

Still missing cityKey and stateKey...not sure what to try next?

UPDATED 05/12/2014 TO ADDRESS RESPONSE DESCRIPTORS...

I had two response descriptors.  I missed posting one in the original description.

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:locationMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"locations"  statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
    RKResponseDescriptor *locationDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:locationsMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:@"/location" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
    
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:locationDescriptor];
```

I changed the structure as recommended but I am still missing the cityKey and stateKey...should I use only one Response Descriptor?

I found an answer to the "use more than one ResponseDescriptor?" here in this article  http://www.softwarepassion.com/parsing-complex-json-with-objective-c-and-restkit/

When I reviewed how the author defined his POJOs, I discovered that only one ResponseDescriptor was required.  The rest is handled in the mapping and defining of relationships...

UPDATED MAY 15 2014

I tested the response descriptors.  Only one was actually working to generate the "It worked" result.  The locationDescriptor was not working at all.  It generated an error when used alone.  It was ignored when used as a part of the pair.  The descriptor that consistently delivered the "It works"  with locations data was responseDescriptor with the keyPath as @"locations".

I read http://blog.mobilejazz.cat/ios-using-kvc-to-parse-json/

I have a question about "...is the expected log output from a custom class that you create but which doesn't have a description method implementation."  What is meant by description method implementation?  What do I need to add to change the following into an NSArray or NSDictionary of mapping results?  Could you share an example based on locations below?

```
2014-05-09 13:18:17.669 MyApp[211:60b] It Worked: {
        locations  =     (
            "<Locations: 0x1780341e0>",
            "<Locations: 0x170027c40>"
        );
```

UPDATED MAY 16 2014  ADDED SUGGESTED NSSTRING DESCRIPTION TO CLASS IMPLEMENTATION FILES

```
response.body={
  "response": {
    "status": "ok"
  }
}
2014-05-16 10:32:26.260 MyApp[202:60b] It Worked: {
    response = "status: ok";
}
```

Therefore, I count the NSString description method implementation answered and working correctly.

SECOND PART OF THE UPDATE IS WITH METHOD DESCRIPTORS IN PLACE I CAN SEE THAT I AM NOT GETTING THE MAPPED JSON TO DATA STRUCTURE VALUES INSTEAD I AM GETTING NULL

```
response.body={
  "locations": [
    {
      "distance": 0.0, 
      "major": 2, 
      "minor": 8, 

    }, 
    {
      "distance": 3.5, 
      "major": 2, 
      "minor": 9, 

    }, 
    {
      "distance": 2.6575364531836625, 
      "major": 2, 
      "minor": 10, 

    }
  ], 
  "cityKey": "10", 

  "stateKey": "21"
}
2014-05-16 09:48:08.328 MyApp[189:60b] It Worked: {
    locations =     (
        "location: (null) city: (null) state: (null)",
        "location: (null) city: (null) state: (null)",
        "location: (null) city: (null) state: (null)"
    );
}
```

First issue is that I should get a location { distance, major, minor} for the three locations in the array of dictionaries and one cityKey and one stateKey.  Here is the mapping code

```
RKObjectMapping* locationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Location class]];
    [locationMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                        @"distance": @"distance",
                                                        @"major": @"major",
                                                        @"minor": @"minor"
                                                        }];


    RKObjectMapping *locationsMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Locations class]];

    [locationsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"cityKey",@"stateKey"]];



    [locationsMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"locations" toKeyPath:@"locations" withMapping:locationMapping]];

 //05/16/2014 this ResponseDesciptor is working
   RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:locationsMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"locations" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
```

Why is it returning multiple cityKey and stateKey for each location?  Why are the results showing null when JSON data returns?

UPDATED MAY 19 2014 EXCEPTION THROWN when keyPath is set to nil and not @"locations"

```
2014-05-19 10:53:53.902 MyApp[245:4907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Locations 0x17022d960> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key locations.'
*** First throw call stack:
```

CODE RAISING IT RestKit code line 364

```
if ([self.dataSource respondsToSelector:@selector(mappingOperationShouldSetUnchangedValues:)] && [self.dataSource mappingOperationShouldSetUnchangedValues:self]) return YES;

    id currentValue = [self.destinationObject valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
    if (currentValue == [NSNull null]) {
        currentValue = nil;
    }
```

Locations Class header file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class Location;


@interface Locations : NSObject




@property (nonatomic, copy) Location *location;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *cityKey;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *stateKey;


@end
```

Locations Class Implementation file

```
#import "Locations.h"

@implementation Locations

-(NSString *)description {

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"location: %@ cityKey: %@ stateKey: %@", self.location, self.cityKey, self.stateKey];
}

@end
```

CHANGED LOCATIONS CLASS PROPERTY FROM

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) Location *location;
```

TO

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *locations;
```

RECEIVED THE DESIRED RESULT when keyPath is nil

```
response.body={
  "locations": [
    {
      "distance": 0.0, 
      "major": 2, 
      "minor": 8 

    }, 
    {
      "distance": 3.5, 
      "major": 2, 
      "minor": 9 

    }, 
    {
      "distance": 2.6575364531836625, 
      "major": 2, 
      "minor": 10 

    }
  ], 
  "cityKey": "1", 

  "stateKey": "1"
}
2014-05-19 14:19:45.040 MyApp[290:60b] It Worked: {
    "<null>" = "location: (\n    \"distance: 0 major: 2  minor: 8 \",\n    \"distance: 3.5 major: 2  minor: 9 \",\n    \"distance: 2.657536453183662 major: 2  minor: 10 \"\n) cityKey: 1 stateKey: 1";
}
```

Which fixed this problem.

Comment: @Wain With your help,I moved closer to mapping the JSON response data.  I am missing the second ,cityKey, and third ,stateKey, top level  JSON objects in the mapping.   I also need to create a description method implementation.  Please review and let me know what you think.  Thanks

Comment: @Wain I changed locationsMapping as suggested.  I received the same locations without the cityKey and stateKey.  Not sure what to try next...I posted the code so that you could review.  Thanks

Comment: @Wain  in the original posted, I missed posting one of my two ResponseDescriptors.  I updated the post to reflect the two Response Descriptors and your suggestion.  I am still missing the cityKey and  stateKey.  Should I only use one ResponseDescriptor?

Comment: @Wain I added this discovered reference http://www.softwarepassion.com/parsing-complex-json-with-objective-c-and-restkit/ to my question...I am reviewing the ResKit Object mapping wiki, this blog posting and your suggestions...I will post my results

Comment: I can't tell if you should have 2 response descriptors as they have different path patterns. I expect that the locations mapping should have a nil keypath and I would remove the other response descriptor until you get the first part working

Comment: @Wain Apologies for delayed update.  I have gotten closer with identifying the correct response descriptor for locations.  I have remapped cityKey and stateKey.  If you could share an example for what description method implementation for custom class locations should look like?  Please reference above update...how do I create a descriptor method implementation for mapping result "It works" above?

Comment: @Wain thank you for explaining description method implementation for custom class.  that worked and it helping to show that I am not getting the desired mappingResult from the JSON data...I posted update...I will continue to work on...please share your thoughts and  comments.  Thank you

Comment: Your response descriptor is all wrong. What is `beaconsMapping` and why is the key path not `nil` ??

Comment: @Wain Corrected the typo..to locations..When I enter both pathPattern and keyPath as nil...I get exception error

Comment: @Wain The Restkit.object.mapping:error is RKMappingOperation.m:440 error failed to transform the value of key at path...to representation of type...I think I know what the issue is...I will fix and get back to you...

Comment: @Wain I fixed the problem with transform type...Which leads to Restkit RkMappingOperation.m  line 355 except break point id currentValue when keyPath is set to nil.  comment points to https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/pull/436 The method in question is shouldSetValue a BOOL

Comment: @Wain  I the responseDescriptor with keyPath as @"" I get the same exception break-point...it appears to need the @"locations" for keyPath...

Comment: Paste the actual exception, and a copy of the line of code that raises it, the key path should be nil. Also, add the `Locations` class to your question (I want to see the data types and any custom methods).

Comment: @Wain I updated the question to include the exception thrown when I use nil as the keyPath for the responseDescriptor.  I also included the Restkit code at the exception break point and the Locations Class files.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: `@property (nonatomic, copy) Location *location;` should be a mutable array called `locations`, not a single location item...

Comment: @Wain I thank you so very much for sticking with this issue until its solution.  I learned a lot.  I posted the final solution response for your review.  Thanks again!!!

Comment: @Wain The result dictionary returned contains a single key\value pair where the key is null.  the value consists of an array locations and NSStrings for cityKey and stateKey.  Do you have any suggestions on how to get the individual values from this dictionary???

Comment: That is how it's logged, but it is actually a dictionary with a null key and the value is a locations object (the log is created by calling the description method).

Comment: @Wain  How do I access the NSDictionary with the null key and value locations object so that I can key\values for locations. cityKey and  stateKey?  Do I need to add a custom method to the Locations class so that I can get to the desired values?

Comment: `objectForKey:[NSNull null]`

Comment: @Wain  First, thanks.  I used the objectForKey:[NSNull null] which did work.  Here's the result and another question...2014-05-22 14:53:49.818 MyApp[258:60b] Your result is: locations: (
    "distance: 0 major: 2  minor: 8 ",
    "distance: 3.5 major: 2  minor: 9 ",
    "distance: 2.657536453183662 major: 2  minor: 10"
) cityKey: 11 stateKey: 19

From  NSString *result = [locations objectForKey:[NSNull null]];
        NSLog(@"Your result is: %@", result );

Comment: @Wain  My new question...Whether I use a string, dictionary or array, I get the above lump sum result which would have to be parsed into key\value pairs.

I need to get key\value pairs for locations array, cityKey and stateKey so that I can use their actual values in the app.  

Would I get a better result if I mapped the data to core data model\ mysql DB?

Comment: Stop reading the log and thinking you have a string. The string is a representation of your locations object so it can be logged, but it is a locations object.

Comment: @Wain  Thanks for your patience and response.  I need to focus on accessing the locations object.  I will let you know my results.  Thanks again!!!

Comment: @Wain I successfully used objectKeyKey: [NSNull null]...which yields the locations object, how do I access locations objects properties such as locations.cityKey, locations.stateKey so that I can use their values in the app?  Do you have an example or reference? I'm not grasping how to access property values within the locations object. How do I get the data within NSArray locations and cityKey and stateKey...from the locations object?

Comment: @Wain Revised comment:I successfully used objectForKey: [NSNull null]...which yields the locations object, how do I access locations objects properties such as locations.cityKey, locations.stateKey so that I can use their values in the app?  I'm trying to use KeyValueCoding, KVC. Do you have an example or reference? I'm not grasping how to access property values within the locations object. How do I get the data within NSArray locations and cityKey and stateKey...from the locations object?

Comment: @Wain Principle is the same for:

response.body={
  "response": {
    "status": "ok"
  }
}

(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        NSLog(@"It Worked: %@", [mappingResult dictionary]);
        NSDictionary *statusResponse = mappingResult.dictionary;
         NSString *status = [statusResponse objectForKey:@"response"];
        NSLog(@"Your status value is: %@",status);

2014-05-27 19:26:10.157 MyApp[232:60b] It Worked: {
    response = "status: ok";
    
}
2014-05-27  MyApp[232:60b] Your status value is: status: ok

How do I simply get the "ok" value?

Comment: Your comment already contains all the correct ideas, like using KVC to drill down into the data to get the bit you want - try it. For arrays you need to get an item at an index. For dictionaries you use a key. For objects you use a property. In all cases it's the same idea to request a piece of information from a container.

Comment: @Wain I have tryed (RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        NSLog(@"It Worked: %@", [mappingResult dictionary]);
        
        //05082014 this code should yeild the same result
        NSDictionary *locations = mappingResult.dictionary;
        
        [locations objectForKey:[NSNull null]];   I know that for the value of this dictionary...I get NSObject isa class Locations...I the code that I have tried locations.cityKey has not worked...I'm searching for how to write the syntax to get the objects in the container?

Comment: @Wain I'm getting closer to solution...NSLog(@"It Worked: %@", [mappingResult dictionary]);
        
        //05082014 this code should yeild the same result
        NSDictionary *locations = mappingResult.dictionary;
        
        Locations *result =[locations objectForKey:[NSNull null]];
        result.locations;
        result.cityKey;
        result.statekey;  This syntax is not complete, but it looks close to what I need...Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Wain  I got it...finished the syntax with is:  NSLog(@"It Worked: %@", [mappingResult dictionary]); //05082014 this code should yeild the same result NSDictionary *locations = mappingResult.dictionary; Locations *result =[locations objectForKey:[NSNull null]]; NSMutableArray *bLocations = result.locations; NSString *cityCode = result.cityKey; NSString *stateCode =result.statekey;  This solved the access issue.  round trip complete...Thanks for all you help over the last few weeks.

Comment: Basically, the class type has to be correct before the compiler will allow you to use dot notation to access the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create `locationsMapping`, `@"locations"` should be added as a relationship using `locationMapping` (not directly as an attribute).

You should have a response descriptor that uses `locationsMapping`.

This:

```
2014-05-07 17:11:47.362 MyApp[145:60b] It Worked: {
    response = "<StatusResponse: 0x16ee2e10>";
}
```

is the expected log output from a custom class that you create but which doesn't have a `description` method implementation.

---

```
RKObjectMapping *locationsMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Locations class]];
[locationsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"cityKey", @"stateKey"]];
[locationsMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"locations" toKeyPath:@"locations" withMapping:locationMapping]];
```

---

On your `Locations` class add:

```
- (NSString *)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"city:%@ state:%@ locations:%@", self.cityKey, self.stateKey, self.locations];
}
```

and a similar method to `Location` class.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I implement your suggestions and post my results.  Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: You weren't supposed to remove the other mappings, just change locations to a relationship mapping...

Comment: I have not grasped how to change locations to a relationship mapping without removing the original locationsMapping.  For example,

Comment: `addAttributeMappingsFromArray:` is not mutually exclusive with `addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping...`. Use both to add plain property mappings and relationship mappings for all of the different keys you're interested in

Comment: I will work use both.  I will get back to you with the result.

Comment: Now you need to fix your response descriptor because it isn't using the `locationsMapping` (it is using `locationMapping`) and it has a key path set to `locations` where it should be set to `nil`

Comment: Updated answer about `description`