# RestKit mapping with NSDictionary and NSArray object

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit, restkit-0.20

```
 {"coord":{"lon":72.62,"lat":23.03},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":303.082,"pressure":1014.85,"humidity":66,"temp_min":303.082,"temp_max":303.082,"sea_level":1018.46,"grnd_level":1014.85},"wind":{"speed":1.07,"deg":340.501},"rain":{"3h":0.435},"clouds":{"all":76},"dt":1475333911,"sys":{"message":0.0033,"country":"IN","sunrise":1475283682,"sunset":1475326567},"id":1279233,"name":"Ahmadabad","cod":200}
```

Above is my API response.

Now I want to mapping of "weather" and "name" and want the same object as a response.

I can create to class

```
@interface WeatherStatus : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) WeatherInfo *info;
@end
```

and

```
@interface WeatherInfo : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *description;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *icon;
```

Below is mapping code.

```
 RKObjectMapping *weatherInfo = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[WeatherInfo class]];
[weatherInfo addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"description": @"description", @"icon": @"icon"}];

RKObjectMapping *weatherStatus = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[WeatherStatus class]];

[weatherStatus addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"name"]];
[weatherStatus addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"weather" toKeyPath:@"weather" withMapping:weatherInfo]];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:weatherStatus method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"weather" statusCodes:nil];

    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

    NSDictionary *queryParams;
    queryParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:kAPP_KEY, @"appid", @"Ahmedabad", @"q", nil];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"/data/2.5/weather" parameters:queryParams success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        WeatherStatus *obj = [mappingResult.array objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"info %@",obj.info);
        NSLog(@"name %@",obj.name);
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"What do you mean by 'there is no coffee?': %@", error);
    }];
```

I am getting

```
info (null)
name (null)
```

Can anyone let me know where is the mistake?

I have already seen [RestKit complex and simple JSON RKObjectMapping almost working, but](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23529494/restkit-complex-and-simple-json-rkobjectmapping-almost-working-but)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the property of info object in "WeatherStatus" class to NSArray.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *weather;
```

Here is the modification of mapping code.

```
RKObjectMapping *venueMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[WeatherStatus class]];
[venueMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"name": @"name"}];

RKObjectMapping *locationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[WeatherInfo class]];
[locationMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"description": @"description",@"icon":@"icon"}];

[venueMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"weather" mapping:locationMapping];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:venueMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:nil];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
```

Add relationship mapping with WeatherStatus class.

Credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1988185/wain

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `description` as a property name, it'll only cause you problems. Use `overview` or something similar instead.

In the JSON, the weather is an array, so you should make your weather (info) property a `NSArray`, and be sure the name in the mapping and the property match.

Comment: I have confusion. in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23529494/restkit-complex-and-simple-json-rkobjectmapping-almost-working-but "location" is in an array format!

Comment: It's a top level array, not nested. This is a key difference.

Comment: That's not what I said to do. Your info property doesn't match the mapping and needs to be an array

Comment: I just catch it! Thanks :)